# Two redirections ssl apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I bought SSL Certificate (https) and I made a redirect from http://example.com to https://example.com

And it's working in 100%.

Now, I want to make, that someone will type `www.site.com` he will be redirect to `https://example.com`

How to make it? I tried with htaccess but it's not working.

Here is a code from /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl which makes redirection from http to https:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) in your virtualhost so that it deals with www.example.com as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```